# A question about sequence and subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Give example of Sequence and Subsequences which satisfy following

1. $\{x_n\}$ is not increasing , but $\{x_n\}$ has increasing subsequence.
2. $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded , but $\{x_n\}$ has a bounded subsequence.
3. A sequence of integers $\{x_n\}$ which diverse , but which has infinitely many distinct subsequnetial limits

for (1) $x_n=\begin{cases} n& n=2k\\\frac1n &n=2k+1\end{cases}$ this not increasing it has increasing subsequence

(2)  consider $x_n = n$ if $n$ is even and $x_n=0$  if $n$ is odd here $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded but $\{x_n\}$ has subsequence

is i am correct for (1) and (2) if i am please can any give example of (3)

Comment: As an aside, any enumeration of the rational numbers will satisfy all three.

Answer (score 8):

Each of your examples work for both (1) and (2). That's nifty. For (3), look at the sequence

$$\{1,\;1,2,\;1,2,3,\;1,2,3,4,\;1,2,3,4,5,\;1,2,3,4,5,6\;,\dotsc\}$$

Comment: This works for all 3 questions.

Answer (score 8):

A fun way of doing (3) is to use primes. (In fact it works for (1) and (2) as well.)
Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by
$$a_n = \cases{p,\quad n = p^k\ \text{for some $p$ prime and $k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$}\\0,\quad \text{otherwise}}$$
Then $(a_n) = \{0,2,3,2,5,0,7,2,3,0,11,0,13,0,0,2,17,0,19,0,0,0,23,0,5,...\}$

The sequence has subsequences converging to every prime, and we know there are infinitely many primes.

**Addendum**

It might look excessive, like it's a lot more complicated than it has to be, but it has the benefit of subsequences being very easy to describe. e.g.

$(a_p)_{p\ \text{prime}} = \{2,3,5,7,11,13,...\}$ is an increasing subsequence

$(a_{2k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}} = \{2,2,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,...\}$ is a bounded subsequence

for each $p$ prime, $(a_{p^k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}} = \{p,p,p,...\}$ is a convergent (constant) subsequence